# Error: "Stack around the variable 'dns1' was corrupted"

Tags: c

Estaba trabajando en uno de los módulos de mi programa en C (mediante Visual Studio), cuando de repente, al compilar, encuentro ese incómodo error que por lo que veo es tan común pero no entiendo a qué puede deberse en este caso concreto. He intentado cambiando el tipo de variables (inviable), nombre, manera de formular sus direcciones, etc. pero sigue apareciendo de tal manera. La verdad, no entiendo a qué puede deberse.

Primero aparece un error del siguiente tipo:
**Debug Error! Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'dns1' was corrupted.**

A continuación, este otro mensaje:
**Debug Error! Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'dns2' was corrupted.**

Acompaño de mi porción de código recortado por si alguien puede determinar a qué se debe, gracias de antemano.

```
void compararDns() {
    FILE* fp;
    char dns1, dns2, str[50];
    int val, val2;

    printf("\n    Escribe la primera IP:\n");
    scanf("%s", &dns1);
    printf("\n\n    Escribe la segunda IP:\n");
    scanf("%s", &dns2);

    strcpy(str, "ping ");
    strcat(str, &dns1);
    strcat(str, " >dns1.txt");
    system(str);
    strcpy(str, "ping ");
    strcat(str, &dns2);
    strcat(str, " >dns2.txt");
    system(str);

    printf("\n    Primera IP: %s\n", &dns1);
    printf("\n    Segunda IP: %s \n", &dns2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estimado Santos,

El problema está en que has definidos las variables dns1 y dns2 con capacidad de almacenar un caracter en vez de un array de caracteres.

En vez de definir:

```
char dns1, dns2, str[50];
```

Deberías cambiarlo a:

```
char dns1[16], dns2[16], str[50];
```

Lo que te permitirá almacenar en ellas, cadenas de hasta 15 caracteres (un IP) mas el \0. También deberás cambiar la forma en que usas estas variables sin el &.

Un ejemplo funcional de lo que te comento lo puedes ver en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char dns1[16], dns2[16], str[50];
    int val, val2;

    printf("Escribe la primera IP: ");
    scanf("%s", dns1);
    printf("Escribe la segunda IP: ");
    scanf("%s", dns2);

    printf("\n* Primera IP: %s\n", dns1);
    printf("* Segunda IP: %s\n\n", dns2);

    printf("Ejecutando pings sobre %s, espere...\n", dns1);
    strcpy(str, "ping -c 5 ");
    strcat(str, dns1);
    strcat(str, " > dns1.txt");
    system(str);

    printf("Ejecutando pings sobre %s, espere...\n", dns2);
    strcpy(str, "ping -c 5 ");
    strcat(str, dns2);
    strcat(str, " > dns2.txt");
    system(str);

    printf("Proceso finalizado.\n");

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Espero te sirva. Saludos!

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. No sólo me has solventado la duda, me has mejorado el código. Sólo una curiosidad: ¿a qué se debe el "-c 5" del ping? He tenido que quitarlo para que me almacene con privilegios debidos en el .txt externo, pero me gustaría conocer tu versión. Un saludo y gracias nuevamente.

Comment: Me alegra saber que te sirve el código. El parametro -c *cantidad* (por lo menos el que yo uso bajo linux), limita la cantidad de pings a la cantidad definida, en este caso a 5 pings.

Comment: Recuerda votar mi respuesta, si te sirvió como dices. Eso incentiva a estar ayudando a la comunidad. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

El problema está aca:

```
char dns1, dns2, str[50];
```

No hace lo que piensas. En vez de definir *dns1*, *dns2* y *str* como un arreglo de 50
caracteres, solamente *str* lo es. Es equivalente a:

```
char dns1;
char dns2;
char str[50];
```

Como `dns1` y `dns2` son de tipo *char* su tamaño es de un byte y al usar *scanf*
con su dirección de memoria corrompe otras variables en el *stack*.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias a ti también por la respuesta y la ayuda.